# Error in commandpromt with laravel: Use of undefined constant ‘role’ - assumed '‘role’'

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, command-prompt, roles

I am making a role function for my users in a laravel application.

Now after this command: php artisan migrate:refresh --seed
I get the following lines back.

Rolling back: 2014_10_12_100000_create_password_resets_table
Rolled back:  2014_10_12_100000_create_password_resets_table
Rolling back: 2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table
Rolled back:  2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table

[ErrorException]
  Use of undefined constant ‘role’ - assumed '‘role’'

I think something in my role migration is not right but I don't know what or how I have to fix it. I shall putt my role migration code below.

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateRolesTable extends Migration
{
  /**
   * Run the migrations.
   *
   * @return void
   */
  public function up()
  {
    Schema::create(‘roles’, function (Blueprint $table) {
     $table->increments(‘id’);
     $table->string(‘name’);
     $table->string(‘description’);
     $table->timestamps();
  });
}

 public function down()
 {
   Schema::dropIfExists(‘roles’);
  }
}
```

Comment: have you added a role in your users table? that's probably why it's failing. can you try  php artisan migrate:refresh --seed -vvv and post the result?

Comment: have you added a role in your users table? that's probably why it's failing. can you try  php artisan migrate:refresh --seed -vvv and post the result?

Comment: all your quote marks are **wrong**

Comment: I get a bunch of lines back but it still has the same error

Comment: I also have added a role in my users table.

Comment: The error means that somewhere in your code you have an unquoted role string - that's why PHP is looking for a constant with this name and as it cannot find it, it assumes you meant a string with a value role. Make sure you put this string in quotes.

Answer (score 1):

You're using wrong quote marks. Replace **‘** with **"** (double quote) or **'** (single quote) and it should resolve your problem.

[image: Visualisation]